# How to move .o on project folder?

Tags: makefile

I wrote this Makefile to move all .o of the project inside a directory 'obj' in the main folder.

#### Directories

```
.:
actor/  lib/  Controller.cpp  Controller.h  Controller.o  doc.txt  main.cpp  main.o  Makefile  uno  VRP*

./actor:
Customer.cpp  Customer.h  Customer.o  Depot.cpp  Depot.h  Depot.o  Route.cpp  Route.h  Route.o  Vehicle.cpp  Vehicle.h  Vehicle.o

./lib:
Search.cpp  Search.h  Search.o  Utils.cpp  Utils.h  Utils.o  VRP.cpp  VRP.h  VRP.o
```

#### Makefile

```
CXX=g++
RM=rm -rf
BIN_NAME=VRP

CPPFLAGS=-s -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall

SRCS=$(wildcard *.cpp actor/*.cpp lib/*.cpp)
OBJS=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SRCS))

all: $(OBJS_DIR) $(BIN_NAME)

$(OBJS_DIR):
    mkdir $(OBJS_DIR)

$OBJS_DIR)/%.o : $(SRCS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $&lt; -o $@

$(BIN_NAME) : $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

debug:
    $(CXX) -g $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(BIN_NAME) $(OBJS)

.PHONY : all clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(OBJS_DIR)

dist-clean: clean
    $(RM) $(BIN_NAME)
```

How can I make it works?

Comment: What actually doesn't work??

Comment: The object files are not moved into the directory 'obj'

Comment: Your `$(OBJS)` still refer to the source directory, not the `$(OBJS_DIR)`: `OBJS=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SRCS))`. You need to prefix these with `$(OBJS_DIR)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `$OBJS_DIR)/%.o : $(SRCS)` sets the prerequisites of *every* file that matches `$OBJS_DIR)/%.o` to **all** the files in `$(SRCS)` that's not even close to what you want. (It is also a typo. You are missing the opening `(`).

You can't write a single rule for what you are trying to do here you need three pattern rules (or one with a `vpath`/`VPATH` setup).

```
$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o: actor/%.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o: lib/%.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

That being said you don't actually have any targets that match `$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o` since the value of `$(OBJS)` is `Controller.o ... actor/Customer.o ... lib/Search.o`. To fix that you also need:

```
OBJS=$(addprefix $(OBJS_DIR)/,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS))))
```

- `$(notdir)` to get just the filename from the source files.
- `$(patsubst)` instead of `$(subst)` just for correctness (subst would have modified a `Bar.cpp.cpp` file to `Bar.o.o`).
- `$(addprefix)` to add the `$(OBJS_DIR)` prefix to the bare object file names.

Comment: you forgot a ')' at the end of OBJS :) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The hazards of writing code in the browser window. Thanks.